# Retrieving data from CSV in PHP

Tags: php, csv

I have a CSV file containing two rows of data, one which the user will input and the other will be returned.  [e.g. inputting a post/zipcode which will be found in the CSV file, the data in the next cell should be returned.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4KiV.png)

```html
<?php
    
function csv_to_array($filename='bn.csv', $delimiter=',')
{
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
        return FALSE;

    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
        {
            if(!$header)
                $header = $row;
            else
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $data;
}



function search($data, $x) {
      for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data); $i++) {
        if($data[$i] == $x) return $i;
        }
        
        return -1;
    }
    
    $data = array("bn.csv");
    
    echo search($data, "BN1 1AA");

print_r(csv_to_array('bn.csv'));
?>
```

Currently I am just getting -1 returned, what should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$data = array("bn.csv");` creates an array with the literal string `bv.csv` in it. I'm guessing you want `$data = csv_to_array("bn.csv");` here instead.  I would build an associative array like this:

```
$data = [
    'BN1 1AA' => 'E05002432',
    '...' => '...',
    '...' => '...',
];
```

Via something like:

```
while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
    $data[$row[0]] = $row[1];
}
```

Thus, you can refer to an entry directly by its key, you don't need to iterate over every item to search for a match:

```
$search = 'BN1 1AA';
if (array_key_exists($search, $data)) {
    echo $data[$search];
} else {
    echo "not found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems towards the end of your code.

In `search()` - you are trying to match the postcode with the entire row in `$data[$i] == $x`, `$data[$i]` is actually a list of the fields in the row, so perhaps matching it with `($data[$i][$field] == $x)` and `$field` is the field name of the postcode.

You were calling `search()` with an array of the file names for the data and not the data from the file, so this code calls `csv_to_array()` first and passes the result to `search()`...

Lastly - the sample data didn't have `BN1 1AA` in it anyway, so should return -1.

```
function search($data, $x, $field = 'Postcode') {
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data); $i++) {
        if ($data[$i][$field] == $x) 
            return $i;
    }

    return -1;
}

$data = csv_to_array('a.csv');

print_r($data);
echo search($data, "BN1 1AD");
```